# Expose domain object metadata to breeze js and track changes

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

I wanted to start using breeze js with an existing application.  This application already has existing service that expose domain objects that are mapped from entity framework data object.

I wanted to expose these domain objects meta data to breeze so i could use it to track these entities on the client side and save changes.  When these changes are saved from breeze I would then work out server side what needed to be done to persist these changes to my data objects.

I've looked at the EF context provider supplied in the breeze samples and was wondering what would be required to create a new context provider that would wrap my domain model ( not DBContext) exposing its metadata and also implement custom saving logic?

Has anyone done this already?  Is there pipeline for breeze I've had a look on the user voice site and it looks like Extensible saveOptions and queryOptions are already under review but there is not much detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a ToDo-NoEF sample provided in the samples zip found [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download).  It shows how to communicate with an arbitrary IQueryable on the server. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: We are just days away from publishing this sample with documentation. It will be known under its new name, **NoDb**. Please watch the **[Samples page](http://www.breezejs.com/samples)**.

Comment: Hi @Ward and Jay thanks for the answer/comments.  I've looked at the sample and it does give me a good starting point for an non EF context provider.  In the sample the metadata is setup client side.  Would it be fairly straight forward to create this server side based on the domain model and a custom provider.  

Does the documentation have a entry for what is the required shape of the metadata needed on the client?

Comment: I do not think it would be trivial. The EF and the WCF Data Services (OData) folks put a ton of talent and effort into metadata generation ... effort we've been harvesting. We have no documentation on how to generate metadata in any other ways ... and we aren't likely to ever write such a thing.

Comment: Actually we have thought about adding a component that would help you generate server side metadata for an Non EF server.  Please vote for this here: https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions

Comment: The NoDb sample is now in the [Samples download zip](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download). [Documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/samples) on the site shortly to follow